# Parse Cloud Promises and Queries

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Im having some trouble doing 2 queries and setting some values for two different classes in Parse. One is the Interest table and the other the User table, when I only do one query and increment the followers it works but when I try to do 2 queries and pass the request.params.follower and the request.params.interestId it seems like if they loose their value and become null which I can't understand why... Here is the code of what Im trying to do, thanks!

```
Parse.Cloud.define("followInterest", function(request, response) {
  var queryInterest = new Parse.Query("Interests");

  queryInterest.equalTo("objectId", request.params.interestId);
  queryInterest.first().then(function(results) {
    results.increment("Followers");
    results.add("Users", request.params.follower);

    var queryUser = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    queryUser.equalTo("objectId", request.params.follower);

    return queryUser.first();
  }).then(function(results) {
    results.add("Interests", request.params.interestId);
    results.save();

    response.success("works");
  }, function(error) {
    response.error("doesnt Works");
  });
});
```

Comment: I think the equalTo("objectId" formulation is wrong.  Instead, do query.get(objectId) and you'll get a single object with that id (or null) as the then() function parameter

Comment: I was already able to handle the problem! I wasn't passing the right parameters to the cloud function!! Sorry about that! It took me a whole day this simple thing!